# Display a red or green button on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, stock

I want to display a **Red** or **Green** button to my customers of our shop stocks. We have 2 attributes where we have this information (it's not a store qty stock). It are 2 similar text attributes.

I have tried this code, but it gives me an error:

```
if ($_product->getvoorraaduden ()):
    if($_product == '' || $_product <= 'onbekend'):
        echo $this->__('onbekend of niets');
    elseif($_product == '0'):
        echo 'Niet op voorraad';
    else:
        echo 'voldoende voorraad';
    endif;
?>
```

I hope you can help me please.

Comment: What error exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand what you want to do with your two attributes, but i'll give you an idea !

First, i edited your code and you forgot to close your `endif;` tag.

Second, check if you get well your attribute `var_dump($_product->getVoorraaduden());` **nb:** there is no space before `()` and `getVoorraaduden()` instead of `getvoorraaduden()` if your attribute is called `voorraa_duden` so it comes `$_product->getVoorraaDuden()` did you understand the trick ? ;)

Finally, check this config of your attribute, `admin->manage attributes->Used in Product Listing-> set it to Yes` then reindex all.

Now you do something like this :

```
if ($_product->getVoorraaduden()) :
    if ($_product->getVoorraaduden() == 'Niet op voorraad'): //here we compare with the attribute value
        echo $this->__('Niet op voorraad');
    elseif($_product->getVoorraaduden() == 'voldoende voorraad'):
        echo $this->__('voldoende voorraad');
    endif;
endif;
```